# Mysql query with table relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

my sql query is normally executed in mysql workbench (despite the 15-second wait), but when I try to run the query from the side of another application (phpmyadmin, etc...) it gives me several errors, such as:

- Timeout
- Error in SELECT clause: expression near '"'.
  Missing FROM clause.

Below is the query code:

```
SELECT        investors_positivador.cod_cliente, investors_saldo_financeiro.nome_cliente, investors_base_assessores.squad, investors_base_assessores.nome_investor, investors_saldo_financeiro.saldo_d0, 
                         SUM(investors_posicao_geral.financeiro) AS vencimentos_ate_data, investors_posicao_geral.vencimento,
                         
CASE WHEN investors_diversificacao.produto = "FUNDO" THEN
    ROUND(SUM( IF( investors_diversificacao.produto = "FUNDO", investors_diversificacao.net / 6, 0 ) ), 2)
 ELSE
    "0,00"
 END AS fundos_ate_data
 
 ,investors_guia_fundos.liquidez_total
 ,investors_positivador.contatar_liquidity_map
 ,investors_positivador.id
 
FROM            investors_positivador INNER JOIN
                         investors_saldo_financeiro ON investors_positivador.cod_cliente = investors_saldo_financeiro.cod_cliente LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         investors_base_assessores ON investors_positivador.cod_assessor = investors_base_assessores.cod_assessor LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         investors_posicao_geral ON investors_positivador.cod_cliente = investors_posicao_geral.cod_cliente
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN investors_diversificacao ON investors_diversificacao.cod_cliente = investors_positivador.cod_cliente AND investors_diversificacao.net != "0,00"
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN investors_guia_fundos ON investors_guia_fundos.cnpj = investors_diversificacao.cnpj

WHERE investors_base_assessores.nome_investor = "Daiane Costa" AND investors_saldo_financeiro.saldo_d0 > 0 AND investors_posicao_geral.financeiro > 0

GROUP BY cod_cliente
```

Comment: increase the timeout perhaps?

Comment: I would like to do this without having to increase the waiting time.. Because it is already very high

Comment: that can be, that they are high, but mysql and phpmyadmin and other methods would send the same query, if you get a different response as workbench you code has a bug and this is taking so long. As i can't see what you are sending, you could try tpo enabke the general log for a **short** while and see what the server actually gets

Comment: I don't think there's much we can do. No idea what it all means. There are two simple tips I can give. 1. Write down queries consistently, with proper indentation, commas in the right place, etc. It won't solve your problem, but will make the query more readable. 2. Check whether you have the correct indexes. Having those can really speed up a query. See also [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html).

Comment: The 2nd error message seems to come from phpmyadmin's internal syntax checker, which is quite buggy. That's not a mysql error.

Comment: Why is your case expression returning two different data types - it should be `else 0 end`

Answer (score 0):

For the waiting time, you could try wrapping your query in a transaction. That may help in optimizing your query

Comment: How would the consultation look like that? I still don't know

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).